# TypeORMError: Entity metadata was not found only for relations

Tags: webpack, nestjs, typeorm

Please help me to understand.
Why Typeorm shows this exception only for relations in Entities?
Everything will be fine if I remove every relation (One-To-One, One-To-Many, Many-To-One, Many-To-Many) from Entity.

**Received error**
[image: Received error]

I work using Webpack + NestJs + Postgre.

**This code (within Webpack)**
generates Entity files from ts to js. Required for running migration.

```js
const ENTITIES_CONFIG = {
  // ... your webpack configurations here...
  // Dynamically generate a `{ [name]: sourceFileName }` map for the `entry` option
  entry: glob
    .sync(path.join(__dirname, "../../src/modules/**/*.entity.ts"))
    .reduce((entries, filename) => {
      console.log(filename, entries);
      entries[path.parse(filename).name] = filename;
      return entries;
    }, {}),

  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    // this is important - we want UMD (Universal Module Definition) for migration files.
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
};
```

**It was Entity.ts**
[image: It was an Entity.ts]

**And became entity.js**
[image: And became an entity.js]

**Scripts in my package.json (There is no any problem)**

```
"typeorm": "cross-env-shell webpack ${npm_package_config_entities} && set NODE_ENV=%npm_package_config_db_migration_env%&& set MIGRATION=true&& ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- -d %npm_package_config_db_config_path% migration:generate %npm_package_config_db_migrations_path%/%npm_package_config_db_migration_name%",
```

**And config for typeorm. Everything works correctly too**

```js
import { registerAs } from "@nestjs/config";
import { config as dotenvConfig } from "dotenv";
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from "typeorm";

dotenvConfig({ path: `env/.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env` });

const config = {
  type: "postgres",
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  // MIGRATION var added using CLI, else - path for the app (auto synchronize)
  entities: process.env.MIGRATION
    ? [__dirname + "/entities/*.entity.js"]
    : [__dirname + "/modules/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  migrations: [__dirname + "/db/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  useUTC: true,
};
console.log(config);

export default registerAs("typeormPostgres", () => config);
export const connectionSource = new DataSource(config as DataSourceOptions);
```